# Is there additional overhead in using D instead of C if I'm writing code to extend interpreted languages?

Tags: d

Maybe D runtime/GC has to initialize and go away every time a function is called, in a way that would not make it useful for adding small do-very-little functions like string to lower, urlencode etc. I'm not sure how this works yet but I've written a few extensions in C.

Comment: I almost thought I have understood the question while reading title but question text itself has made me reconsider. Could you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the D runtime has to initialise when the D program starts, and (depending on what libraries you use) static constructors need to be called. It's minimal, but like you said, it would be inefficient for small functions.

The druntime is open source. Here's [druntime's `main` function](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/rt/dmain2.d#L346).

If you are just exporting functions through a C interface (using `extern(C)`) and calling those then there is no need to start up the runtime, although you shouldn't use the GC or rely on static constructors etc. if you do that.

Comment: But why should it be necessary to initialize the runtime every time a function is called? He probably just creates a shared library that extends a scripting language.

Comment: What part of D is not open source?

Comment: D is a language, so the question really does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

It really, really depends on your use case.

I have several scripts in D that display memory% usage, cpu% usage, system load, etc.
I run them as scripts using #!/usr/bin/env rdmd 
as the first line in the file, and making them executable.

The script is compiled once on it's first run, and then the cached executable is run every 2-3 seconds to update it's tally.

They only run for a few milliseconds before they've done their job, and shut down until
they are run again.  (I did turn the GC off, since it will never need to free anything anyways.)

Yeah, there's a cost to using them.  No it's not great.
Yes, it's orders of magnitude better than say, Python.  And people still use Python for what I'm using D for.  I'm not arguing that I *might* get better performance in C, or C++.

I'm arguing that for my use-case, it truly does not matter.